# How should "NewUserClient" be implemented

Tags: c++, macos-catalina, iokit, macos-system-extension, driverkit

I am trying to interact with a dext from an application. I am able to find the service using `IOServiceOpen` and I get a call to `NewUserClient` of my dext (I can see the `type` parameter passed being output in the log). After this I am a bit lost. Reading here about [NewUserClient](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325581-newuserclient?language=objc)  I can see that one should use [`Create`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?language=objc) to create a new Service object.

The Discussion part [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?language=objc) says *The keys in the `propertiesKey` dictionary describe the new service.*

Should this dictionary be placed in the plist file for the system extension as a top level entry, or should the dictionary be placed with the key in `IOKitPersonalities`?

Can I leave the `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` key with an empty value to not impose any restrictions about entitlements on the application that is connecting to the system extension?

My plist looks like this (with the `MyUserClientProperties` key / dict in two places).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
  <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>  
  <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>  
  <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>  
  <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>  
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>  
  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>  
  <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>  
  <string>6.0</string>  
  <key>CFBundleName</key>  
  <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>  
  <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>  
  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>  
  <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>  
  <string>1.0</string>  
  <key>CFBundleVersion</key>  
  <string>1</string>  
  <key>MyUserClientProperties</key>  
       <dict>  
           <key>IOClass</key>  
           <string>MyUserClient</string>  
           <key>IOUserClass</key>  
           <string>MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>  
           <key>IOServiceDEXTEntitlements</key>  
           <string></string>  
       </dict>  
  <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>  
  <dict>  
  <key>example_device</key>  
  <dict>  
      <key>MyUserClientProperties</key>  
           <dict>  
               <key>IOClass</key>  
               <string>MyUserClient</string>  
               <key>IOUserClass</key>  
               <string>MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>  
               <key>IOServiceDEXTEntitlements</key>  
               <string></string>  
           </dict>  
  <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>  
  <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>  
  <key>IOClass</key>  
  <string>IOUserService</string>  
  <key>IOProviderClass</key>  
  <string>IOUSBHostInterface</string>  
  <key>IOUserClass</key>  
  <string>MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>  
  <key>IOUserServerName</key>  
  <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>  
      <key>bConfigurationValue</key>  
      <integer>0x1</integer>  
      <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>  
      <integer>0x0</integer>  
      <key>idVendor</key>  
      <integer>0x123</integer>  
      <key>idProduct</key>  
      <integer>0x08</integer>  
  </dict>  
  </dict>  
    <key>OSBundleUsageDescription</key>  
    <string>Example user space USB driver</string>  
</dict>  
</plist>
```

Do I need to pass `SUPERDISPATCH` as the last argument to `Create`?

From "OSX and iOS kernel programming" chapter 5 page 81:

*The ingenuity of the I/O Kit design is that user client objects are themselves a driver object: the IOUserClient class inherits from IOService and, as with any other IOService instance, each user client has a provider class that, for a user client, is the instance of the driver that the application is controlling.*

While the above might only be correct for kext (?) I would assume that things work in the same way for a dext,

From [Create](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?language=objc) documentation: *Use the kIOUserClassKey key to specify the name of the custom IOService subclass that you want the system to instantiate.*

Why is another `IOService` class needed to be instantiated? What is the purpose of this class? Is it the provider for my class that inherits from `IOUserClient`? If so how can I make the instance of my driver (the one that implements `NewUserClient`) the provider?

From [Create](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?language=objc) documentation: *Use the `kIOClassKey` to specify the name of the custom `IOUserClient` subclass to return to clients of your service.*

Is the type of the class that will be created and assigned to the third argument of `Create`? If so, is that the one I should assign `IOUserClient*` pointer to, which is passed to `NewUserClient`?

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver, NewUserClient) {  
  os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, "%{public}d:", type);  

  IOPropertyName propertiesKey = "MyUserClientProperties";  

  IOService* client;  

  auto ret = Create(this, propertiesKey, &client, SUPERDISPATCH);  
  // Need to do more things here...  
  return ret;  
}
```

No matter what I try I always get an assert, but I cannot see what is causing it.

```
3   com.apple.DriverKit            0x0000000102f2b24b __assert_rtn + 102  
4   com.apple.DriverKit            0x0000000102f2c20a IOService::Create_Impl(IOService*, char const*, IOService**) (.cold.2) + 35  
5   com.apple.DriverKit            0x0000000102f1766b IOService::Create_Impl(IOService*, char const*, IOService**) + 91  
6   com.apple.DriverKit            0x0000000102f2668f IOService::Create_Invoke(IORPC, OSMetaClassBase*, int (*)(OSMetaClassBase*, IOService*, char const*, IOService**)) + 135  
7   com.apple.DriverKit            0x0000000102f276d7 IOService::Create(IOService*, char const*, IOService**, int (*)(OSMetaClassBase*, IORPC)) + 267  
8   sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver 0x0000000102ee0c89 MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver::NewUserClient_Impl(unsigned int, IOUserClient**) + 313 (MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver.cpp:155)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as the WWDC presentation on DriverKit tried to pretend otherwise, DriverKit's view of the world is very different from the kernel's and you need to be aware of some implementation details, because the abstraction is extremely leaky.

As you've probably already discovered, what looks like an `IOService` object in your DriverKit driver is actually an `IOUserService` object in the kernel's (and user space's) view of the I/O registry. The gap is bridged via DriverKit's IPC mechanism.

For creating a new user client, you want an instance of a (kernel) `IOUserClient` subclass, which is backed by your (dext) `IOUserClient` subclass. The kernel class for this is actually `IOUserUserClient`. (Yes, really.) As you've found, the documentation isn't exactly clear on how you go about this. I found it helpful to take a look at what's available in terms of source code - the kernel side of invoking `NewUserClient` [is implemented in the `IOUserServer::serviceNewUserClient()` function here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-6153.61.1/iokit/Kernel/IOUserServer.cpp.auto.html).

One thing you'll notice straight away is that if the `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` property is missing, this won't prevent the code from succeeding:

```
            prop = userUC->copyProperty(gIOServiceDEXTEntitlementsKey);
            ok = checkEntitlements(entitlements, prop, NULL, NULL);
```

and in `checkEntitlements`:

```
    if (!prop) {
        return true;
    }
```

This is great news as it means we don't need to worry about it for the minute, and can simply leave it off.

Next, it turns out that the `propertiesKey` refers to a property *on the provider `IOUserService` kernel object*. You can't set those properties from inside the dext's code, so the only way to provide them is from the IOKit matching personality dictionary.

You can name this property however you want, but:

- Its value must be a dictionary.
- It must contain the `"IOClass"` key-value pair, specifying the *kernel* class to instantiate as a string - in your case, `"IOUserUserClient"`
- It must contain the `"IOUserClass"` key-value pair. This specifies the *dext* class to instantiate, again as a string. In your case, that looks like `MyUserClient`.

Putting it together:

```
  <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>  
  <dict>
    <key>example_device</key>  
    <dict>  
      <key>MyUserClientProperties</key>
      <dict>
        <key>IOUserClass</key>
        <string>MyUserClient</string>
        <key>IOClass</key>
        <string>IOUserUserClient</string>
      </dict>
      <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
      <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
      …
    </dict>
  </dict>
  …
```

Then, from your `NewUserClient` function, call:

```
    IOService* client = nullptr;
    kern_return_t ret = this->Create(this, "MyUserClient", &client);
```

I don't believe `SUPERDISPATCH` is needed here, as you presumably don't override the `Create` method in your class, so you super-implementation is inherited anyway.

Then do your error checking, any other initialisation, preparation, etc. you might need, and finally:

```
    *userClient = client;
    return kIOReturnSuccess;
```

Comment: Great. The assert is now gone and I can see calls to `MyUserClient::init()` and `MyUserClient::Start_Impl(IOService *)` being logged. But I get a non successful return code (`-536870174`) from `IOServiceOpen`. Also, when I detach the device the dext process is not terminated. If I don't call `IOServiceOpen` the dext process is terminated.

Comment: @tuple_cat The error code `0xE00002E2` is `kIOReturnNotPermitted`. You probably need to add the `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` entitlement to your user space process (array of dext bundle ID strings).

Comment: I am calling `IOServiceOpen` from the app that activates the dext with `OSSystemExtensionManager`. I added the `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` entitlement to the target that produce the `.dext` bundle.

Also tried to the entitlement to the app that makes the call to `IOServiceOpen`, but I still get `kIOReturnNotPermitted`

Comment: @tuple_cat This follow-up seems to exceed the scope of SO comments, can you open a new question please, ideally including all the app‘s entitlements and relevant code? I‘ll definitely take a look (I look at **all** questions tagged with `iokit` or `driverkit`)

Comment: Yes, good idea. Created new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613403/kioreturnnotpermitted-from-ioserviceopen-connecting-to-systemextension-ioservice