# kIOReturnNotPermitted from IOServiceOpen connecting to SystemExtension IOService

Tags: c++, macos-catalina, iokit, macos-system-extension, driverkit

I am trying to create a client connection to a SystemExtension IOService. I can see that my `IOUserClient` subclass is created (`init()` and `Start(IOService*)` is called), but the return code from `IOServiceOpen` returns `kIOReturnNotPermitted`.

I am making the call to `IOServiceOpen` from the same app that creates the activation request.

Entitlements for app that makes the activation request / call to `IOServiceOpen`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access</key>
  <array>
    <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
  </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.install</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.system-extension.uninstall</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Entitlements for the dext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access</key>
  <array>
    <string>sc.example.USBApp</string>
  </array>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

MyUserClient:

```
#ifndef MyUserClient_h
#define MyUserClient_h

#include <DriverKit/IOUserClient.iig>

class MyUserClient : public IOUserClient {
public:
  bool init() override;
  kern_return_t Start(IOService* provider) override;
  kern_return_t Stop(IOService* provider) override;
  void free() override;
};

#endif /* MyUserClient_h */
```

```
bool MyUserClient::init() {
  LOG();
  if (!super::init()) {
    LOG("super::init() failed");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

kern_return_t IMPL(MyUserClient, Start) {
  LOG();
  auto ret = Start(provider, SUPERDISPATCH);
  if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG("SUPERDISPATCH Start failed, ret: %{public}d", ret);
  }
  return ret;
}

kern_return_t IMPL(MyUserClient, Stop) {
  LOG();
  auto ret = Stop(provider, SUPERDISPATCH);
  if (ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG("SUPERDISPATCH Stop failed, ret: %{public}d", ret);
  }
  return ret;
}

void MyUserClient::free() {
  super::free();
  LOG();
}
```

`LOG` is just a macro that does `os_log(OS_LOG_DEFAULT, ...`

`NewUserClient` implementation:

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver, NewUserClient) {
  LOG("%{public}d:", type);

  IOService* client;

  auto ret = Create(this, "UserClientProperties", &client);
  *userClient = OSDynamicCast(IOUserClient, client);
  if (!(*userClient) || ret != kIOReturnSuccess) {
    LOG("Failed to create IOUserClient, %{public}d", ret);
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Code to connect to system extension:

```
void connectToDext(io_service_t* serviceObject) {
  io_connect_t dataPort;

  kern_return_t kernResult =IOServiceOpen(*serviceObject, mach_task_self(), 123, &dataPort);
  if (kernResult != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("IOServicceOpen failed: %d, %s\n", kernResult, kern_return_t_toCStr(kernResult));
  }
  kernResult = IOServiceClose(dataPort);
  if (kernResult != KERN_SUCCESS) {
    printf("IOServicceClosed failed: %d, %s\n", kernResult, kern_return_t_toCStr(kernResult));
  }
}

int connectToFirstDext() {
      CFMutableDictionaryRef matchingDict;
      matchingDict = IOServiceMatching("IOService");

      if (matchingDict == 0) {
        return -1;
      }

      io_iterator_t iter;
      if (IOServiceGetMatchingServices(kIOMasterPortDefault, matchingDict, &iter) !=
          KERN_SUCCESS) {
        printf("IOServiceGetMatchingServices failed.\n");
        return -1;
      }

      io_service_t device;
      while ((device = IOIteratorNext(iter))) {
        io_name_t deviceName;
        if (IORegistryEntryGetName(device, deviceName) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
          printf("name: %s\n", deviceName);
          if (strcmp(deviceName, "MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver") == 0) {
            printf("Calling connect\n");
            connectToDext(&device);
          }
        }
        IOObjectRelease(device);
      }

      IOObjectRelease(iter);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

Info.plist of app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>19E287</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>USBApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>sc.example.USBApp</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>USBApp</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>11E503a</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string>19E258</string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>macosx10.15</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>1141</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>11E503a</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>10.15</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2020 Example. All rights reserved.</string>
    <key>NSMainNibFile</key>
    <string>MainMenu</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSSupportsAutomaticTermination</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSSupportsSuddenTermination</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Info.plist of dext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
    <string>19E287</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>DEXT</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
    <array>
        <string>MacOSX</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>DTCompiler</key>
    <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
    <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
    <string>11E503a</string>
    <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
    <string>GM</string>
    <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>DTSDKName</key>
    <string>driverkit.macosx19.0</string>
    <key>DTXcode</key>
    <string>1141</string>
    <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
    <string>11E503a</string>
    <key>IOKitPersonalities</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example_device</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
            <key>IOClass</key>
            <string>IOUserService</string>
            <key>IOProviderClass</key>
            <string>IOUSBHostInterface</string>
            <key>IOUserClass</key>
            <string>MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
            <key>IOUserServerName</key>
            <string>sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver</string>
            <key>UserClientProperties</key>
            <dict>
                <key>IOClass</key>
                <string>IOUserUserClient</string>
                <key>IOServiceDEXTEntitlements</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>IOUserClass</key>
                <string>MyUserClient</string>
            </dict>
            <key>bConfigurationValue</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <key>bInterfaceNumber</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <key>idProduct</key>
            <integer>8</integer>
            <key>idVendor</key>
            <integer>1234</integer>
        </dict>     
    </dict>
    <key>OSBundleUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Example user space USB driver</string>
    <key>OSMinimumDriverKitVersion</key>
    <string>19.4</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: I had the entitlements definitely wrong first. changed so that `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` is an array of strings. Still get kIOReturnNotPermitted.

Comment: @pmdj This page says that `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` should be a boolean:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_driverkit_userclient-access

I tried with boolean first but also then I got  `kIOReturnNotPermitted`.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, can you please also post your Info.plist? (post-build)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` being boolean only applies to dext entitlements, not app entitlements. It's only needed on the dext if your dext needs to act as a client to another dext. But I haven't actually tried that yet, and none of my dexts has `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` set at all. (The apps do, however.)

Comment: Note also that `com.apple.developer.driverkit.transport.usb` is not a boolean entitlement, but an array of usb matching dictionaries, but this should not affect your user client connecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated answer:

The `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` property in your IOKitPersonality's  `Info.plist`'s user client property dictionary should be one of:

1. **Missing entirely**; this means: *don't check client entitlements beyond basics listed below in my original answer.*
2. *I think*, **an array of arrays of strings**; the client must have *all* the entitlements listed in *one* of the inner arrays. (NB: I haven't done any testing with this latter case.)

A non-array or empty-array `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` property means the client *can't match the entitlements in **one** of the inner arrays, as there aren't **any**.* The check therefore **always fails** with `kIOReturnNotPermitted`. This is what's happening with your (empty) string value.

For details, check the code in `IOUserServer::checkEntitlements()` and where it's called from in `IOUserServer::serviceNewUserClient()` in IOUserServer.cpp from the xnu source code.

#### Original answer:

(Given prior to the contents of the `Info.plist`s being posted.)

I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you've posted, so I suspect your problem might be caused by something you *haven't* posted. Things to watch out for:

- The user client app's `com.apple.developer.driverkit.userclient-access` array must contain the dext's bundle ID. Perhaps double-check that this ID really is equal to `sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver`? (I've previously spent over an hour tearing my hair out over the `kIOReturnNotPermitted` error when I had a typo here.)
- The user client app must be permitted to talk to IOKit. This is the case by default, unless your app is sandboxed. Assuming the entitlements you've posted are *complete*, your app isn't sandboxed, so that shouldn't be the problem.
- If the dictionary used for creating the new user client contains the `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` key, the user space app must have all entitlements listed there. (This dictionary comes from the dext's info.plist, which you haven't posted yet at time of writing.)
- I believe the dext and the app must be signed using the same team ID. (I seem to remember there is an entitlement you can set on the dext to work around this requirement however.) Perhaps double-check the `TeamIdentifier` using `codesign -dv path/to/your.dext` and `codesign -dv path/to/your.app`

Comment: Double checked the id. It is `sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver`. Entitlements that I posted are complete and I updated the questions with Info.plists for both app and dext. The `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` is an empty string. Maybe I should remove that key?

I checked the `TeamIdentifier` with `codesign`, it is the same for both app and dext. I think the entitlement for allowing different identifiers is `com.apple.developer.system-extension.redistributable` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_developer_system-extension_redistributable

Comment: Yes, try removing the IOServiceDEXTEntitlements key entirely. It should be either missing or an array of strings.

Comment: Removing `IOServiceDEXTEntitlements` did it!

Comment: @tuple_cat Great! I've updated my answer with a better explanation why your original Info.plist was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Tangential to your question - I'll try to answer your actual question separately - but I noticed you're locating your service by iterating over all `IOService` objects. You can find it much more elegantly by matching it directly using property matching. I use a helper function for generating the matching dictionary that looks something like this:

```
// Creates IOKit matching dictionary for locating driverkit-based service objects
// (Corresponds to kext services' IOServiceMatching())
static CFMutableDictionaryRef user_service_matching(CFStringRef driverkit_classname, CFStringRef driverkit_server_bundle_id) CF_RETURNS_RETAINED
{
    CFMutableDictionaryRef match = IOServiceMatching("IOUserService");
    CFTypeRef match_property_keys[]   = { CFSTR("IOUserClass"), kIOBundleIdentifierKey };
    CFTypeRef match_property_values[] = { driverkit_classname,  driverkit_server_bundle_id };
    CFDictionaryRef match_properties = CFDictionaryCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault,
        match_property_keys, match_property_values, 2,
        &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFDictionaryAddValue(match, CFSTR(kIOPropertyMatchKey), match_properties);
    CFRelease(match_properties);
    return match;
}
```

This matches:

- Objects of type `IOUserService` (This is a much smaller search space than `IOService` and all direct `IOService` subclasses in dexts are actually `IOUserService` objects in the "real" (kernel) I/O Registry.)
- With the `IOUserClass` property matching the provided `driverkit_classname` (this would be `CFSTR("MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver")` in your case)
- With the `CFBundleIdentifier` matching the provided one. (`CFSTR("sc.example.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver")`)

Although relatively unlikely, the service *name*, as retrieved via `IORegistryEntryGetName` in the code you posted, could in theory collide with other kexts or dexts, whereas there should be no ambiguity in the bundle identifier, and matching the user class is helpful when your driver implements multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly!