# OSDynamicCast not compiling in basic driver kit example

Tags: c++, macos, iokit, driverkit

I've got a very simple driver kit driver. It's almost boiler plate.

I'm getting a build failure when trying to use `OSDynamicCast`, as per the below

```
kern_return_t IMPL(MyHIDDriver, NewUserClient) {
   
    IOService* client;
    
    auto ret = Create(this, "MyTest", &client);
    *userClient = OSDynamicCast(IOUserClient, client);
    return ret;
}
```

My use of OSDynamicCast is giving me the following issue.

> Use of undeclared identifier 'gIOUserClientMetaClass'; did you mean 'gIOUserServerMetaClass'?

Before adding the `NewUserClient` override, the driver was running fine (I've observed it in the IORegistry).

I'm not sure what I'm missing here in Xcode that would cause this issue. Samples I've referenced, [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613403/kioreturnnotpermitted-from-ioserviceopen-connecting-to-systemextension-ioservice), do exactly what I'm doing with OSDynamicCast.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `IOUserClient` header `#include`d somewhere in this compilation unit? It sounds like you're simply missing

```
#include <DriverKit/IOUserClient.h>
```

Entirely unrelated to the issue you're experiencing, but you may want to initialise the `client` variable to a `nullptr` to avoid issues with undefined behaviour in case `Create` fails:

```
IOService* client = nullptr;
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit/ioservice/3325579-create?changes=_6) does not guarantee that it will be set to this automatically if the call fails, so the subsequent `OSDynamicCast` would be exposed to undefined behaviour.