# How to call a function from one Dext to another Dext?

Tags: macos, driverkit

i am trying to write a code to call a function from one dext to another dext.
i have gone through the below link, it has information about sext to dext communication.
[How should "NewUserClient" be implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61545594/how-should-newuserclient-be-implemented)

may i know any function(or class) for Dext to Dext communication?
how to call a function from one dext to another dext?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have two iig, one is for your user space driver.
the other one is for your iouserclient.
These two iigs form a dext.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).